# Google Sheets API V4(Java) / How do I pass Credetials to the Sheets object?

Tags: java, google-sheets-api, google-oauth

[In the Quickstart sample code](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/java),the 3rd argument is **Credentials**, but in the API documentation, it is **httpRequestInitializer**. 
I am getting compile error.

**Sample code in Quickstart** ([link](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/java))

```
new Sheets.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_ FACTORY, ★getCredentials(HTTP_TRANSPORT)★)
```

**■API Document**([link](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/sheets/v4/java/latest/))

```
Builder(HttpTransport, JsonFactory, ★httpRequestInitializer★)
```

[image: Image from Gyazo]

**■Environments**

- java 1.8
- sheets library `com.google.apis:google-api-services-sheets:v4-rev581-1.25.0`

Comment: The quickstart doesn't work for you? Can you please post the error stack trace?

Comment: Thank you for  Alessandro. There is no stacktrace. Because it cannot be executed due to a compilation error.

Comment: So the quickstart is not working for you?

Comment: yes. not working.

Comment: That is really odd, the quickstart runs fine following the instructions. Can you please post the error you are getting from trying to run the quickstart? Plus check the [troubleshooting section](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/java#troubleshooting) for additional help.

Comment: Dear Alessandro

Thank you for your kindness. m(_)m

My application is web, I don't have OAuth issues, OAtuh authentication has been successful and Credential can be obtained by.

The problem is that the Credential is passed to the Sheet instance It's that the interface doesn't exist in the actual library. (Even though it's listed in QuickStart.)

My conclusion is that "Google is wrong" (inconsistency between the library implementation and QuickStart).

PS…sorry.I think my English is poor and difficult to understand.

Comment: I see, the quickstart actually runs fine with that version of the library. I tested myself and I had no problems. Please add the error you are encountering in your question.

Comment: The constructor Sheets.Builder(...)  is udefined..Please refer to the screenshot below.

https://gyazo.com/a9cab81196999e784c0d2f2949fbbde7

■definition of this constructor 
https://gyazo.com/49d2287f5d080953e93d4dde1c7b9093

Answer (score 0):

### Solution

In your example you are using `GoogleCredentials` Class that according to this [documentation](https://googleapis.dev/java/google-api-client/latest/com/google/api/client/googleapis/auth/oauth2/GoogleCredential.html) is deprecated, while the Quickstart example it's using the `Credential` Class from the `com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential` package.

The `Credential` Class implements `HttpRequestInitializer` interface, using it you won't incur in any compile error. Following the quickstart at [this link](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/java) is a perfect starting point to learn how to use the `Credential` class in the Sheets service builder.